# how can I switch channels dynamically?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-composer

I have two channels; how do I switch channels in the run time so that the peer can dispatch the transactions based on the values in each transaction?

Answer (score 1):

The name of the channel to use is in the connection profile, so you need to create a second `BusinessNetworkConnection` that references a different connection profile (and hence channel).

https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/jsdoc/module-composer-client.BusinessNetworkConnection.html

Comment: Thx Dan; instead of using an existing channel can I use hyperledger-composer to create a connection profile on the fly? Tried the doc and did not find it though. Is that by design, meaning, a channel creation should be an offline admin. work? Thx

Comment: Composer does not create channels or provide any features to manage the physical infrastructure of Fabric. That is by design. We assume that managing the Fabric is an operational concern, whereas Composer makes it easy to create solutions that run on a Fabric. You can create a connection profile dynamically (our unit tests do that, see the AdminConnection methods) but the channel would still have to exist.